# How to use notifyAll() to resume a thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to use Object.notifyAll() method to resume a thread that is pasued with Object.wait() in Java. Currently, a client will connect to a socket, then a condition is asked, if the client hasBall is true or not. If it's true, the client can pass the ball via a method to another client. If not, the client must wait to receive the ball - this is where lock.wait() is called.

The problem is that the lock.notifyAll() call is not waking the lock.wait() call.

**Code:**

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
    
    public class ClientInterface extends Thread {
    
        private final Client client;
        final static Object lock = new Object();
    
    
        public ClientInterface(Client client){
            this.client = client;
        }
    
    
        public void pass(String playerId) throws Exception {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("\nYou currently have the ball.");
                System.out.println("Enter ID of player you wish to pass to...");
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                client.passBall(playerId, line);
                System.out.println("Pass ball to player #" + line);
    
        }
    
        public void receive() throws InterruptedException {
                System.out.println("waiting");
                System.out.println("\nPlayer #" + client.getPlayerWithBall() + " currently has the ball.");
        }
    
    
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
    
                    System.out.println("Connected to Ball Game successfully.\n");
    
                    while (true) {
    
                        // Get the list of all players currently connected to the server
                        String[] players = client.getPlayers();
                        // Get the ID generated for this client
                        String playerId = client.getPlayerId();
                        boolean hasBall = Objects.equals(playerId, client.getPlayerWithBall());
    
                        System.out.println("Your ID is : #" + playerId + '\n');
                        System.out.println("List of current in-game players:");
                        int count = 1;
                        //Print the ID strings of each player
                        for (String player : players) {
                            System.out.println("[" + count + "] ID: #" + player);
                            count++;
                        }
    
                        // Check if the player currently has the ball or not
                        // If they don't have the ball, print waiting, and call wait on object lock
                        try{
                            synchronized (lock){
                                while (!hasBall){
                                    receive();
                                    lock.wait();
                                    System.out.println("resumed");
                                }
                            }
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
    
                        // Allow player with ball to send ball to another client
                        // call notify on object lock so thread can unlock if they now have the ball
                        synchronized (lock){
                            try {
                                pass(playerId);
                                lock.notifyAll();
                            }catch (Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
    
                    }
    
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            Client client = new Client();
            ClientInterface c = new ClientInterface(client);
            if(client.getPlayers().length > 0){
                c.start();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Expected Outcome**

The first client joins with the ball. A second client joins without a ball. Client 2 is waiting for the ball. Client 1 passes the ball to Client 2. Client 1 updates, no longer has ball. Client 2 updates, now has the ball.

**Actual Outcome**

As expected, BUT Client 2 will not update when it receives the ball.

(also posted on code ranch, incase someone else answers it there: https://coderanch.com/t/747213/java/notifyAll-resume-thread-Java)

Answer (score 0):

There's many things wrong with this code. First, you're using a static lock object when you really should be synchronizing on the client instance itself. The major problem is that hasBall is a variable and not a function. You can't just ask if the variable is changing when nothing is changing it.

Comment: When I run multiple instances of "ClientInterface.java", the variable "hasBall" is changed from an instance that passes the ball. If I remove both synchronized blocks and just have: if(hasBall){pass(playerId);}else{receive();}, a client that receives a ball will update, but because there is no wait() call, the while loop will repeat indefinitely and therefore (undesirably) print the client ID and list of players indefinitely.